# Looping through text file in a folder with numpy loadtxt

Tags: python, numpy, loops, text

I have several .txt file with similar name, such as data_00, data_01, ..., data_99. I tried to use **np.loadtxt** in a for loop to read it.
Now, I can use r-string to read the values in the text file manually
`numerical = np.loadtxt(r'file_path\data_0.txt', delimiter=' ')`, it is working but I am thinking to loop through the files.

So when I tried to use f-string, but it is giving me error "**SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape**"

```
number = np.arange(100)

for i in number:
    numerical = np.loadtxt(f'file_path\data_{i}.txt', delimiter=' ')
```

I also tried to use glob to import the value, (code shown below), not it is not giving me the correct values in same order.

```
file_path = 'file_path' 
file_pattern = "*.txt"

files_list = glob(os.path.join(file_path,file_pattern))

for f in files_list:
    print(f'----- Loading {f} -----')
    numerical = np.loadtxt(f, delimiter=' ', unpack=True)
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You didn't make your f-string into an r-string. You need to use `/`, `fr` or `\\ `.

Comment: Try double```\\``` instead of single ```\```.

Comment: @MadPhysicist it is not clear

Comment: @nnaem. OP has an error, wants to not have an error

Comment: @MadPhysicist oh wow I didn't know that, if he at least briefly explained what he's trying to do that would help a lot in solving his problem

Comment: @nnaem. I think the question is quite clear and unambiguous. I'm currently drafting an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`r'file_path\data_0.txt'` is a raw (or r-) string. That means that `\` is treated as a literal backslash. Without the `r` prefix, it would have a special meaning as the escape character for strings.

`f'file_path\data_{i}.txt'` is an f-string. That means that `{i}` gets special treatment, but `\` does not. The escape sequence `\U` (presumably in your actual path) must be followed by 8 hexadecimal digits that make up the code for a Unicode code point. Clearly this is not what you are looking for.

There are a few solutions available to you:

1. Escape the `\`:

   ```
   f'file_path\\data_{i}.txt'
   ```

   This places a single backslash in your string
2. Make the string both f- and raw:

   ```
   fr'file_path\data_{i}.txt'
   ```
3. Stay away from backslashes entirely. Python understands forward slash as the path separator:

   ```
   f'file_path/data_{i}.txt'
   ```
4. Have a function, like `os.path.join` add the path separator for you:

   ```
   os.path.join('file_path', f'data_{i}.txt')
   ```
5. Use an r-string, with the `format` method instead of the newer f-string functionality:

   ```
   r'file_path\data_{}.txt'.format(i)
   ```